# Ad-hoc WLAN configuration with 2 adapters

Tags: wifi, networking

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B configured to work with two different Wi-Fi USB dongles. The first one (`wlan0`) creates an ad-hoc wireless network using `hostapd`, while the second one (`wlan1`) *should* try to connect to my home network using `wpa_supplicant`. Here's the relevant part of my `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
# Ad-hoc wireless interface
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 172.16.42.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0

# Infrastructure wireless interface
allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet dhcp
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

While `hostapd` serves the ad-hoc network, clients are given an IP address using `dnsmasq`.

Now, *sometimes* everything work fine: I boot my Raspberry Pi, my ad-hoc network is broadcasted, DHCP by `dnsmasq` works fine, and the second interface connects to my home Wi-Fi and gets an IP address.

However *some other times*, it happens that while the ad-hoc network is initialized and works perfectly, the second interface does not connect to my home network and, instead, it gets an IP address from the first one. When this happens, here's the output of `ifconfig`:

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  
          inet addr:172.16.42.1  Bcast:172.16.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          ...

wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  
          inet addr:172.16.42.18  Bcast:172.16.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          ...
```

Note that `wlan1`'s `inet addr` should be the one provided by my home router, and not that one.

I thought that maybe this problem has to do with boot order: `dnsmasq` may be started too early or too late, but I'm not sure. What do you think? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I've changed your title since every 10th post here is "Problem w/ WLAN configuration" and it is tempting for people to just ignore them.